# Change the definition of the vertex buffer from an imported model

Tags: c#, xna

I want to change the vertex defition from a model. I have a definition called VertexPositionColorNormal. But the code errors on the draw statement that there isn't any color.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You may want to post some actual code and the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the Effect. My guess is that you have Effect.UseVertexColor True. Either set it false for models without vert color or change the artwork.